# Why does my CSS3 animation stops for a few miliseconds in each percentage range using @keyframes?

Tags: css

I am trying to make a sailing ship animation. It works, but it is not a smooth animation. It stops in each change I make in the `@keyframes`. I'm using `transform:rotate(-5deg)` and then it changes to `5deg` to simulate the waves effect, at the same time I make it moves changing the "left" values, but and the result is awful. What piece of css code am I missing to have my animation running soft and smoothly?

Here is code:

```
div {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  top: 20px;
  background-image: url('https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/c2/bb/ae/c2bbaed0207deef5775af9c01e1b31ba.jpg');
  position: relative;
  background-size: cover;
  animation: mymove 5s linear infinite alternate;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform:translate3d
  transition: all;
}

@-webkit-keyframes mymove {
  from,
  20% {
    trans: -2%;
    transform: rotate(5deg)
  }
  20%,
  30% {
    left: 20%;
    transform: rotate(-5deg)
  }
  40%,
  50% {
    left: 40%;
    transform: rotate(5deg)
  }
  60%,
  70% {
    left: 60%;
    transform: rotate(-5deg)
  }
  80%,
  90% {
    left: 80%;
    transform: rotate(5deg)
  }
  90%,
  100% {
    left: 100%;
    transform: rotate(-5deg)
  }
}
```

Comment: Remove codes like 20% and keep 20%{}

Comment: You have one for 20 percent then another one for 20 and 30 percent. Try to keep the percentage separate.

Comment: Thank you for replying! I changed those  2 percentages  separated by commas , and did the animation changes using only 1 percentage for each change..! now it moves smoothly..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add 2 percent values like `20%, 30% { ... }`, `40%, 50% { ... }`, etc., the rules applied will be the same between those 2 steps/values, hence it stops for a few milliseconds.

If to remove 1 of the percent values, and you can also remove the `left` from all but the first and last, you get a smooth animation

```css
div {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  top: 20px;
  background-image: url('https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/c2/bb/ae/c2bbaed0207deef5775af9c01e1b31ba.jpg');
  position: relative;
  background-size: cover;
  animation: mymove 5s linear infinite alternate;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform:translate3d
  transition: all;
}

@-webkit-keyframes mymove {
  from,
  0% {
    left: -150px;
    transform: rotate(5deg)
  }
  20% {
    transform: rotate(-5deg)
  }
  40% {
    transform: rotate(5deg)
  }
  60% {
    transform: rotate(-5deg)
  }
  80% {
    transform: rotate(5deg)
  }
  100% {
    left: 100%;
    transform: rotate(-5deg)
  }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

---

If to use the same syntax as in your original CSS, one can combine the rules that has the same property/value, like this.

```css
div {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  top: 20px;
  background-image: url('https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/c2/bb/ae/c2bbaed0207deef5775af9c01e1b31ba.jpg');
  position: relative;
  background-size: cover;
  animation: mymove 5s linear infinite alternate;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform:translate3d
  transition: all;
}

@-webkit-keyframes mymove {
  from,
  0% {
    left: -150px;
  }
  20%, 60%, 100% {
    transform: rotate(-5deg)
  }
  0%, 40%, 80% {
    transform: rotate(5deg)
  }
  100% {
    left: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Thanks! That was really helpful!

Comment: @JulioRodriguez Great...and please also consider accept it as well